# Set translation domain for every twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some twigs include the text which needs to be translated.

Currently I put this sentence in every twig.

```
{% trans_default_domain 'AcmeTopBundle' %}
```

However it is a little bit bothering.

Is there a good way to set default domain for every twigs in one place??

Comment: Could you not put this in your base template in app/resources/views/base.html.twig?

Comment: I am not using the base template.So I woud like to se the default_domain in php.

Comment: I'm afraid that including `trans_default_domain` in every template is the way to go. Moreover, please note that this tag doesn't apply to any included template (via `include()` function or `{% include %}` tag), so you have to add it too to those templates (if any).

Comment: I see. I found that this tag is not applied to include template. It looks a bit redundant way though, it can't be helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom node visitor based on the original `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\NodeVisitor\TranslationDefaultDomainNodeVisitor`:

https://gist.github.com/connorhu/3254272188d81d1f9d7322dbdebeb0e0