# Set default translation domain based on parameter in Symfony and Twig

Tags: php, git, symfony, twig, translation

A Symfony application is deployed on two different servers, since almost every thing is the same, we're using one codebase and show or don't certain things in the frontend.

In our `app/config/parameters.yml` file we have the line `page: foo` at one server and at the other `page: bar`. We then inject this to every twig template as global variable in our `config.yml` file at the twig section like this:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    [...]
    globals:
        foobar: '%page%'
```

This seams to work as when we dump it in any twig file `{{ dump(foobar) }}` we get the right value.

The issue however is with the translation files. Since the two applications share one git repo, we need a way to decide what's the default translation domain, that one application will load `messages_foo.xliff`, while the other loads `messages_bar.xliff`

In our twig files we therefore added:

```
{% if foobar == 'bar' %}
    {% trans_default_domain "messages_bar" %}
{% else %}
    {% trans_default_domain "messages_foo" %}
{% endif %}
```

However when extracting the translations, it only extracts `messages_foo` no matter what value `foobar` has. We've then copied `messages_foo.xliff` and named the copy `messages_bar.xliff`, changed a value in there, cleared the cache and made sure the config param was `bar`, however twig still rendered the value for the `messages_foo.xliff` file, completly ignoring `messages_bar.xliff`.

Is there a way to achieve this? The only way to achieve it without dynamically setting the default_domain, would be to have in git besides the `master` branch a `foo` and `bar` branch, merge new features first in the `master` and then merge `master` both in `foo` and `bar`, which seams kind of an overengineering to me.

Another thing we've tried was to use instead of a if else construct to simply call `{% trans_default_domain foobar == 'bar' ? "messages_bar" : "messages_foo" %}` which resulted in an error:

```
[LogicException]                                                        
Attribute "value" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node_Expression_Name".
```

The command to extract messages was: `php bin/console translation:extract en --config=user --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --output-format=xliff`

Note:

- It seams to be possible to use variable for the default translation domain: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8469
- I'm aware, that we can't set the default translation domain globaly: [Set translation domain for every twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242721/set-translation-domain-for-every-twig) (AFAIK there's also no way to set it in a controller or the config (which would probably solve the issue at hand, so if you know something let me know))

Comment: Are The translations in the template where you changed trans_default_domain ? Because from symfony doc "Note that this only influences the current template, not any "included" template (in order to avoid side effects)."

Comment: Yes they are - As stated in the Note at the bottom, I'm fully aware of this. To test it further I created a new symfony application with just one controller, and one action with one twig file. It's the same situation. I'm aware, that it doesn't propagate through extends, includes and so on.